# Is is possible to manually increment/set the commit number in Subversion?

Tags: svn

We use subversion's commit number as a build number.  I'm on a different repo now, and want to adjust the Subversion commit number so it is inline with the original repo.  Is this possible?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No. Short of making a bunch of commits to the new repo to make the number match.

I'd recommend appending the svn revision number or the build system build id to the semantic version.  For example, if you had
`1.2.0-3344` in the old repo, you could bump the number in the new repo to `1.2.1-1` (assuming the code didn't change enough to up other parts of the version).

TL;DR - build numbers alone don't uniquely identify. You won't likely  be able to control the build numbers to the degree you want. Build numbers are helpful to decorate version numbers.